# Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}), s<s_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I read articles where they talk about functions being in  $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ for all $s<s_0$ for some specific $s_0$. For example in my case it is 1/2 or 3/2. I see this set can be written as an intersection of infinitely many Sobolev spaces. My question is: is that a Sobolev space? If so what would be the inner product in that space?

Comment: Actually, probably a _union_... And, no, not literally a Sobolev space in the simplest sense. So probably not Hilbert or Banach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a Sobolev space.

Take for example $f(x) = \mathcal{F}((1+|y|^2)^{-(s_0+1/2)/2})$ where $\mathcal{F}(u) = \hat{u}$ is the Fourier transform. Then
$$
∫_{\mathbb{R}}|\widehat{f}(x)|^2 \,(1+|x|^2)^s \,\mathrm{d}x = ∫_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|x|^2)^{s-s_0-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which is finite if and only if $s<s_0$. So $f∈H^s$ for every $s<s_0$. So if there is a Sobolev space $H^{s_1}$ such that $H^{s_1} = \bigcap_{s<s_0} H^s$, then $s_1<s_0$. But then we can take $s'\in(s_1,s_0)$ and $g(x) = \mathcal{F}((1+|y|^2)^{-(s'+1/2)/2})$ is in $H^{s_1}$ but not in $\bigcap_{s<s_0}H^s$.

Therefore, $\bigcap_{s<s_0} H^s$ is not a Sobolev space.

---

Actually, you have some more refined spaces $B^s_{2,q}$ called Besov spaces verifying
$$
H^{s_0} = B^s_{2,2} ⊂ B^s_{2,\infty} \subset \bigcap_{s<s_0} H^s ⊂ H^{s_0-\varepsilon}
$$
but even here I think the inclusion is strict.

Comment: Thank you! So, to give a concrete example: u=exp(-|x|). Just computing the Fourier tranform, it tells you that it is in $H^s$ for all s<3/2.  So, I could say it is in H^1.49 for example, but I could not characterize u as part of a "optimal" Hilbert (instead of asking it to be Sobolev) space other than by making s closer to 3/2?

Comment: Yes, this function is actually in $B^{3/2}_{2,\infty}$, which is a bit more precise than $\bigcap_{s<3/2} H^s$, which is a Banach space but I think it is not a Hilbert space. You can also look at the non $L^2$ setting and say that this function is Lipshitz continuous (Which is the Sobolev space $C^{0,1} = W^{1,\infty}$), but once again, this is not a Hilbert space.

Comment: @ LL 3.14 Thank you again. A Banach space would work for me. Would you mind telling me the name of the B space you mention so I can look it up please?

Comment: The spaces $B^s_{p,q}$ are called Besov spaces. They are an extension of Sobolev spaces $W^{s,p}$, the index $q$ being the additional refinement.

Actually, if you want a Hilbert space more precise than $∩_{s<3/2} H^s$ *for the particular function* $u = e^{-|x|}$, you can take the norm
$$
∫ |\hat{f}(x)|^2\,\frac{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}{1+\ln(1+|x|)^2}\,\mathrm{d} x
$$
(I think it defines a Hilbert space), but there might be other functions in $∩_{s<3/2} H^s$ that are not in this space.

Comment: @ LL 3.14 If I can still pull your chain: that norm is really a good idea. I would not mind having a little bit more, as long as the functions I want are in. So, I would have to check the Cauchy property, right? Also, I read a little about Besov spaces. Is there a way to say if a given function is in a Besov space. Also, why choose $q=\infty$? Thank you again.

Comment: So the reason for the $\infty$ index is that this is the largest Besov space included in $\bigcap_{s<s_0} H^s$ since
$$
B^{s}_{2,1} ⊂ B^{s}_{2,p} ⊂ B^{s}_{2,2} = H^s ⊂ B^{s}_{2,q} ⊂ B^{s}_{2,\infty} ⊂ \bigcap_{s<s_0} H^s
$$
for any $1≤ p≤ 2≤ q≤ \infty$

Comment: To compute the Besov norm, you can use the Littlewood-Paley decomposition (you can look at whatever book on Besov spaces, for example "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations" by Bahouri, Chemin & Danchin, or https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~isabelle.gallagher/littlewoodpaley.pdf Definition 6.2.1. Then you get
$$
\|\Delta_j e^{-|x|}\|_{L^2} ∼ 2^{-3j/2}
$$
so that
$$
\|e^{-|x|}\|_{B^{3/2}_{s,\infty}} = \|2^{3j/2}\|\Delta_j e^{-|x|}\|_{L^2}\|_{\infty} < C
$$

Comment: @LL3.14 I am going through the stated book, however I find the book quite terse but the linked note proved to be very helpful in following the book. Do you know where can I access the remaining notes in this series, as it is chapter 6?